# Proof of Levi Problem via L^2 estimate

Tags: several-complex-variables

A theorem of Grauert says that a complex manifold admitting a strictly plurisubmanonic exhaustion function is stein. There is a proof by $L^2$ estimate in Domailly' notes "$L^2$ estimate for the dbar operator on complex manifolds", page 43. The idea is to construct nontrivial holomorphic functions via $L^2$ estimate. 
The existence of strictly plurisubharmonic function $\phi$ is crucial here.
However, it is not clear to me why we need to assume $\phi$ is an exhaustion function? In a complete kahler manifold $M$ with positive bisectional curvature, the Busemann function is strictly plurisubharmonic, but we do know if it is exhausted. Can we use $L^2$ estimate to conclude that $M$ is stein?

Comment: On any open subset of a Stein manifold there is a strictly plurisubharmonic function, but clearly, not all such subsets are Stein.

Comment: On a complete K\"hler manifold M with positive bisectional curvature, the Busemann function is Lip continuous and strictly plurisubharmonic, however, we don't know if it is a exhaustion function. We do know if it is, if we assume Riemann sectional curvature is positive, this is a result of Greene-Wu.

Comment: Speaking of the proof of ''construction of holomorphic functions with prescribed values and order along a discrete sequence of given points'' by L^2-methods, I read briefly P43 of Demailly's notes. We do need the weight function to be an exhaustion strictly PSH function, which is important, for example, in the final steps to conclude the solution from d-bar equation vanishes up to given order along given sequence. If the weight function is not exhaustion, then it might attains +\infty at these points,  then the last inequality of the proof on P43 does not necessarily hold.

Comment: picard l-adic and hartogs in math ann 62(1906) is a must read